docker compose exec with | xargs
In my docker container I run this command to update all dependencies
composer show --no-dev --direct --name-only | xargs composer require

But when I try to run this with exec (I try to use it in a shell script) i get an error
docker compose exec (Try with -T) php composer show --no-dev --direct --name-only | xargs composer require
xargs: composer: No such file or directory

Is there a solution to update all dependencies outside of my docker-container

You wouldn't typically use docker exec for tasks like this: anything you do this way will be lost as soon as the container exits.  Will rebuilding the underlying image and recreating the container reinstall the library dependencies as well?

Yes. My goal is to update all dependencies of a laravel aplication with a shell script outside of container. In this shell script i rebuild all nescessary items. The application data are in a volume

| is a shell command. You can execute everything in the shell inside the container.
docker compose exec sh -c '
   php composer show --no-dev --direct --name-only | xargs composer require
'

